# UIView subviews' order?

Tags: ios, subview, addsubview, subviews

If i use a for loop;

```
for(UIView *subview in [myView subviews])
```

in which order, subviews are brought?

According to their added order or something else?

Comment: Something else. You just need to fire up the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW17) and you'll easily find it out.

Comment: but you can also check UIClass such like if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) // Check is SubView Class Is UILabel class?
        {
            // You can write code here for your UILabel;
        }

Comment: @iPatel I don't see how that's relevant to the question.

Comment: @H2CO3 - yup but i just want to inform to OP that you can also get it like this, so.. i putted it as comment also :) thanks :)

Comment: The order of the subviews in the array reflects their visible order on the screen, with the view at index 0 being the back-most view.
this is what says subviews method description.

Answer (score 8):

As the documentation says, it reflects their visible order in the screen.

> @property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews
>
> **Discussion**
>
> You can use this property to retrieve the subviews associated with
>   your custom view hierarchies. The order of the subviews in the array
>   reflects their visible order on the screen, with the view at index 0
>   being the back-most view.
>
> For complex views declared in UIKit and other system frameworks, any
>   subviews of the view are generally considered private and subject to
>   change at any time. Therefore, you should not attempt to retrieve or
>   modify subviews for these types of system-supplied views. If you do,
>   your code may break during a future system update.

Comment: I'm probably not really good in English, but what is "visible order"? How does it count? What is back-most? Back-most from which side? Does it mean the order the subviews were added to their superview?

Comment: Old question and comment, but @AndreyChernukha, back meaning the farthest view from the viewer, the bottom of the stack in a 3D hierarchy.  When you add views, they get added to the top of the stack, so the order is almost the same as added order, except for explicit re-orderings.

Comment: @ChrisConover Thanks a ton, buddy. That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I find it to be useful, and in my experience it places `subviews` in order that they were added. Just be careful using them when using `UIScrollView`. I occasionally ran into 'phantom' `subviews` that are created for scroll bars